# Check for available command

Tags: linux, bash

When I execute the bash script with root user I receive the output it say iptables not exist. Why this happens only with root?

```
for CMDAPP in "hash" "curl" "iptables"
  do

    if ! hash "$CMDAPP" 2>/dev/null
    then

        echo "`date`: $MODULE ended without '$CMDAPP' command." >> ERROR.log
        exit

    fi

  done
```

Comment: My guess is that the `iptables` command does not exist in the root's  `PATH`. Try `which iptables` as normal user and use that absolute path.

Comment: As root (`sudo su -`) type `export PATH=$PATH:/sbin/:/usr/sbin/` and then type `iptables -h`.  If you get the help documentation for iptables, the issue is your $PATH variable, which you can set permanently by editing [/root/.bashrc](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Path-Variable-in-Linux)